# What is the correct way to join multiple path components into a single complete path in emacs lisp?

Tags: elisp, filenames, path-manipulation

Suppose I have variables `dir` and `file` containing strings representing a directory and a filename, respectively . What is the proper way in emacs lisp to join them into a full path to the file?

For example, if `dir` is `"/usr/bin"` and `file` is `"ls"`, then I want `"/usr/bin/ls"`. But if instead `dir` is `"/usr/bin/"`, I still want the same thing, with no repeated slash.

Comment: The wording of the title ("join multiple path components") is really a bit more general than the actual problem, but if anyone is looking for a solution which handles values of "multiple" > 2, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694661

Comment: Well, if you can join two components, then you can use recursion to join an arbitrary number. I suppose I consider the two problems equivalent by induction.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Reading through the manual for [Directory Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Names.html#Directory-Names), you'll find the answer:

> Given a directory name, you can combine
>   it with a relative file name using
>   `concat`:
>
> ```
>  (concat dirname relfile)
> ```
>
> Be sure to verify that the file name is
>   relative before doing that. If you use
>   an absolute file name, the results
>   could be syntactically invalid or
>   refer to the wrong file.
>
> If you want to use a directory file
>   name in making such a combination, you
>   must first convert it to a directory
>   name using `file-name-as-directory`:
>
> ```
>  (concat (file-name-as-directory dirfile) relfile)
> ```
>
> Don't try
>   concatenating a slash by hand, as in
>
> ```
>  ;;; Wrong!
>  (concat dirfile "/" relfile)
> ```
>
> because this is not portable. Always
>   use `file-name-as-directory`.

Other commands that are useful are: `file-name-directory`, `file-name-nondirectory`, and others in the [File Name Components](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html#File-Name-Components) section.

Comment: Duh, no wonder I see those `concat` all over the place, even our manual encourages this use.  But it's generally much better to use `expand-file-name`, except in those cases where you want the end result to be a relative file.

Comment: Why is `expand-file-name` preferred over `concat`? Other than the style issue, I don't see the practical benefit?

Comment: Might you also want to call `convert-standard-filename` on the result if interested in portability?

Comment: @SamBrightman: No, `convert-standard-filename` should basically only be used with *constants*, e.g. to define the actual name to use for `~/.emacs`.  Most other uses are simply confused.

Comment: Okay, but the manual suggests it makes names e.g. DOS compatible; that doesn’t seem specific to constants. Why would I not want to ensure such compatibility? E.g. I construct a full path from a prefix and some data - I rather get the platform safe version than an error.

Answer (score 35):

You can use `expand-file-name` for this:

```
(expand-file-name "ls" "/usr/bin")
"/usr/bin/ls"
(expand-file-name "ls" "/usr/bin/")
"/usr/bin/ls"
```

Edit: this only works with absolute directory names. I think Trey's answer is the preferable solution.

Answer (score 15):

I wanted to join multiple nested directories onto a path. Originally I used multiple `expand-file-name` calls, like so:

```
(expand-file-name "b" (expand-file-name "a" "/tmp"))
"/tmp/a/b"
```

However this is rather verbose, and reads backwards.

Instead I wrote a function which acts like Python's `os.path.join`:

```
(defun joindirs (root &rest dirs)
  "Joins a series of directories together, like Python's os.path.join,
  (dotemacs-joindirs \"/tmp\" \"a\" \"b\" \"c\") => /tmp/a/b/c"

  (if (not dirs)
      root
    (apply 'joindirs
           (expand-file-name (car dirs) root)
           (cdr dirs))))
```

It works like so:

```
(joindirs "/tmp" "a" "b")
"/tmp/a/b"
(joindirs "~" ".emacs.d" "src")
"/Users/dbr/.emacs.d/src"
(joindirs "~" ".emacs.d" "~tmp")
"/Users/dbr/.emacs.d/~tmp"
```

Comment: @dbr, I use a similar function -see my answer be below. Care to comment on what I outlined as the differences and their pros/cons?

Answer (score 12):

This question was asked in 2010, but at the time of writing it's the top hit for searches like *"join file paths in elisp"*, so I thought I'd update the answer.

Since 2010, things have moved on a lot in the world of Emacs. This is somewhat of a duplicate answer since it was mentioned briefly in an answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22404052/3255378), but I'll flesh it out a little. There's now a [dedicated library](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) for file interactions, [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el):

> Much inspired by [@magnars](https://github.com/magnars)'s excellent [s.el](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) and [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el), [f.el](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) is a modern API for working with files and directories in Emacs.

Don't try to reinvent the wheel. You should use this library for file path manipulations. The function you want is [`f-join`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-join-rest-args):

```lisp
(f-join "path")                   ;; => "path"
(f-join "path" "to")              ;; => "path/to"
(f-join "/" "path" "to" "heaven") ;; => "/path/to/heaven"
```

You may need to install the package first. It should be available on MELPA.

Comment: This should be the top answer, hoping this is merged into Emacs mainline so we finally have a standard file interface. Can add f.el using use-package as follows: ```(use-package f :demand)```

Comment: Your comment doesn't work in default Emacs.  Never *EVER* assume your environment (I suspect it's some "distribution" like Doom or Space) is the standard.

Answer (score 7):

For those who come to the question after 2021. elisp builtin function `file-name-concat` would do the job. It's much simpler now.

Document can be found in emacs with following keystroke:

`C-h f file-name-concat <enter>`

> Append COMPONENTS to DIRECTORY and return the resulting string.
>
> Elements in COMPONENTS must be a string or nil.
> DIRECTORY or the non-final elements in COMPONENTS may or may not end
> with a slash -- if they don't end with a slash, a slash will be
> inserted before contatenating.
>
> Other relevant functions are documented in the file-name group.
> Probably introduced at or before **Emacs version 28.1.**
> This function does not change global state, including the match data.

```lisp
(file-name-concat "/usr/bin/" "ls")
;; ==> "/usr/bin/ls"

(file-name-concat "/usr" "bin" "ls")
;; ==> "/usr/bin/ls"
```

Comment: You might want to note the emacs version in which this function was added.

Comment: From the document, it says "Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 28.1."

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I use:

```
(defun catdir (root &rest dirs)
  (apply 'concat (mapcar
          (lambda (name) (file-name-as-directory name))
          (push root dirs))))
```

Differences from @dbr's:

1. Returns an "emacs directory name", i.e. a value with a trailing slash
2. It does not expand the path if `root` is relative (see notes)
3. Treats `root` as the root, whereas `joindirs` will use the *first* component starting with `"/"` as the root.

**Notes**

Many file handling functions (all, most, ???) will normalize redundant slashes and call `expand-file-name` (or similar) on relative paths, so #2 and #3 may not really matter.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a convenient file and directory manipulation library [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el), you only need [`f-join`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-join-rest-args). The below code is for those, who for some reason refuse to use this library.

```
(defun os-path-join (a &rest ps)
  (let ((path a))
    (while ps
      (let ((p (pop ps)))
        (cond ((string-prefix-p "/" p)
               (setq path p))
              ((or (not path) (string-suffix-p "/" p))
               (setq path (concat path p)))
              (t (setq path (concat path "/" p))))))
    path))
```

This behaves exactly as Python's [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

```
ELISP> (os-path-join "~" "a" "b" "")
"~/a/b/"
ELISP> (os-path-join "~" "a" "/b" "c")
"/b/c"
```

`string-suffix-p` doesn't exist [before Emacs 24.4](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/02/02/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-new-string-manipulation-functions/), so i wrote my own at [Check if a string ends with a suffix in Emacs Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22403751/596361).

Comment: This isn't portable, is it? It uses forward slash as the directory separator and assumes a root that begins with slash.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete what was said before with a link to the Emacs manual:

As others have said before, the answer to the OP question is to use the `expand-file-name`.  That is a built-in function, implemented in C and therefore does not require the use of any external library.

This is described in the [Emacs Lisp Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html) section titled [Functions that Expand Filenames](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html).

And according to Emacs on-line help this function was introduced in version ... 1.6 of Emacs!  So... it should be available!