# In Elisp, how to get path string with slash properly inserted?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am manually constructing path strings in Elisp by concatenating partial paths and directory names.  Unfortunately sometimes the paths end with slash, sometimes not. Therefore, I need to insert slash before concatenating a directory name when necessary but not otherwise.  What's a good way to do this?

Comment: on linux, doubled // symbols in a file path are usually (always I think) interpreted as a single /, so having an extra one shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This needs to work on all platforms.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`(file-name-as-directory dir)` will return directory path `dir` with a trailing slash, adding one if necessary, and not otherwise.

If you had your sequence of partial paths in a list, you could do something like:

```lisp
(let ((directory-list '("/foo" "bar/" "p/q/" "x/y"))
      (file-name "some_file.el"))
  (concat
   (mapconcat 'file-name-as-directory directory-list "")
   file-name))

"/foo/bar/p/q/x/y/some_file.el"
```

or as an alternative, if you wanted to include the file name in the list, you could utilise `directory-file-name` which does the opposite of `file-name-as-directory`:

```lisp
(let ((path-list '("/foo" "bar/" "p/q/" "x/y/some_file.el")))
  (mapconcat 'directory-file-name path-list "/"))

"/foo/bar/p/q/x/y/some_file.el"
```

(Someone please correct me if using `directory-file-name` on a non-directory is not portable?)

Comment: What if it has a piece starting with `/` e.g. `"/p/q/"`?

Comment: If it's at the start, then there's no problem (as per my example above). If it's not at the start, well an absolute path has no business being in the middle of a sequence of path components, so that would suggest a bug in the logic that generated that sequence.

Comment: Isn't it a portability problem that you're explicitly using a "/" in the econd example?

Comment: Clément: No, it's been a very long time since differentiating the directory separator for different systems was recommended. The old `directory-sep-char` variable was removed entirely in Emacs 24, but it's been deprecated since version 21. Assuming that it's Emacs which is going to be using the resulting path, you should use `/` on all systems -- Emacs ensures that it works.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to assemble file names from parts of questionable content is with expand-file-name.  For example:

```
(expand-file-name "foo.txt")
```

this common form will give you a full file name based on default-directory:

```
/home/me/foo.txt
```

but if you have a variable 'dir' whose content is "/home/them/subdir" and want to use that, do this:

```
(expand-file-name "foo.txt" dir)
```

it doesn't matter if dir ends in / or not.  If you are on some other platform, and contains the other slash, it will do the right thing then too.  Do you have a mix?  Just stack them:

```
(expand-file-name "foo.txt" (expand-file-name "somesubdir" dir))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work as a starting point, although you'd want to flesh it out a bit to make it platform independent, etc.

```
(defun append-path-component (path new-part)
  (if (string-match ".*/$" path)
    (concat path new-part)
    (concat path "/" new-part)))
```

As per usual, there's probably some bit of elisp that already does this that I'm just not aware of.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, I was looking for those possibly-existing built-in and featureful function.

Comment: This is a portability fail.  You shouldn't have to ever type a path separate in your lisp code.

Comment: event_jr: `directory-sep-char` is long obsolete, and has been removed entirely in Emacs 24. The old docstring said "The value is always `?/`.  Don't use this variable, just use `/`."

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really care about keeping relative file names as relative, then it's always much better to avoid `concat` and use `expand-file-name` instead.

Comment: Could you please given an example to illustrate the difference of the two?

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun* tofilename (directorylist &optional (filename nil))
  "concatenate directory names into a path, with an optional file name as last part"
  (concat
   (mapconcat 'directory-file-name directorylist "/")
   "/"
   filename))


(tofilename '("~/" "Temp/") "temp.txt")
;; => "~/Temp/temp.txt"

(tofilename '("~/" "Temp/"))
;; => "~/Temp/"

(tofilename '("~/" "Temp/" "test"))
;; => "~/Temp/temp/"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with file manipulation, joining and splitting filepaths, checking empty directories and such, I strongly recommend installing [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el), modern file manipulation library. You will have a huge set of file and filepath manipulation functions under one namespace and will never reinvent the wheel again.

The function you need is [`f-join`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-join-rest-args), it concatenates parts of a path, adding slash only where needed.