# Check if a string ends with a suffix in Emacs Lisp

Tags: string, emacs, elisp, substring, string-matching

Is there a function that checks that a string ends with a certain substring? Python has [`endswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=endswith#str.endswith):

```
>>> "victory".endswith("tory")
True
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just install [`s.el`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) string manipulation library and use its [`s-suffix?`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-ends-with-suffix-s-optional-ignore-case) predicate:

```
(s-suffix? "turn." "...when it ain't your turn.") ; => t
```

But if you refuse you to use this library, you have to write your own function. There is [`string-prefix-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Comparison.html#index-string_002dprefix_002dp-255), which is an analog to Python's [`str.startswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=startswith#str.startswith), in `subr.el`, and it is just a wrapper around [`compare-strings`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Comparison.html#index-compare_002dstrings-256). According to [Emacs 24.3 changelog](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.24.3):

```
** New function `string-prefix-p'.
(This was actually added in Emacs 23.2 but was not advertised at the time.)
```

`string-suffix-p` was [added only in Emacs 24.4](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/02/02/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-new-string-manipulation-functions/), so for earlier versions i wrote:

```
(defun string-suffix-p (str1 str2 &optional ignore-case)
  (let ((begin2 (- (length str2) (length str1)))
        (end2 (length str2)))
    (when (< begin2 0) (setq begin2 0))
    (eq t (compare-strings str1 nil nil
                           str2 begin2 end2
                           ignore-case))))
```

`(when (< begin2 0) (setq begin2 0))` is a workaround, because if you pass negative numbers to `compare-strings`, it barfs with `*** Eval error ***  Wrong type argument: wholenump, -1`.

If you byte compile the function, it works faster than [yves Baumes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83331/yves-baumes) solution, even though `string-match` is a C function.

```
ELISP> (setq str1 "miss."
             str2 "Ayo, lesson here, Bey. You come at the king, you best not miss.")
ELISP> (benchmark-run 1000000 (string-suffix-p str1 str2))
(4.697675135000001 31 2.789847821000066)
ELISP> (byte-compile 'string-suffix-p)
ELISP> (benchmark-run 1000000 (string-suffix-p str1 str2))
(0.43636462600000003 0 0.0)
ELISP> (benchmark-run 1000000 (string-match "miss\.$" str2))
(1.3447664240000001 0 0.0)
```

Comment: `compare-strings` is implemented in C as well, likely as a simple byte-wise memory comparison, whereas `string-match` needs to compile and run a RE state machine for the test.  Unsurprisingly that's orders of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 10):

You may use a regex with a call to the `string-match` function.

```
(if (string-match-p "tory\\'" "victory")
    (message "victory ends with tory.")
   (message "victory does not ends with tory."))
```

Comment: You didn't escape the dot, so in this version it matches any char before txt, not just a dot (e.g. it also matches *footxt*)

Comment: -1: `$` matches the end of a **line**.  You must use `\\'` to match the end of the string.

Comment: Also, you should use `string-match-p` to preserve `match-data`.

Comment: @lunaryorn Also ``(string-match "\\.txt$" "foo.txtAAA")`` returns nil which is the expected result. Do you have a counter-example please?

Comment: @yvesBaumes `(string-match "\\.txt$" "foo.txt\nAAA")`